# frequency table including names of observations

Tags: r, frequency

I am wondering whether the following can be done in a more efficient and 'elegant' way:

I have data similar to the one below which contains country names (location) and the number of agreements a country has joined (no.agreements):

```
d <- structure(list(location = c("Afghanistan", "Angola", "Bangladesh", 
                                     "Bosnia-Herzegovina", "Burundi", "C\x99te d'Ivoire", "Cambodia", 
                                     "Chad", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo", "Croatia", "Democratic Republic of Congo (Zaire)", 
                                     "Djibouti", "El Salvador", "Georgia", "Guatemala", "Guinea Bissau", 
                                     "Haiti", "India", "Indonesia", "Liberia", "Macedonia", "Mali", 
                                     "Mexico", "Moldova", "Mozambique", "Nepal", "Niger", "Papua-New Guinea", 
                                     "Philippines", "Rwanda", "Senegal", "Serbia (Yugoslavia)", "Sierra Leone", 
                                     "Somalia", "South Africa", "Sudan", "Tajikistan", "Uganda", "United Kingdom"
    ), no.agreements = c(3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 
                         1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                         1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("location", 
                                                                                                  "no.agreements"), row.names = c(1L, 4L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 15L, 19L, 
                                                                                                                                  20L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 36L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 
                                                                                                                                  45L, 47L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 58L, 61L, 64L, 65L, 
                                                                                                                                  66L, 68L, 71L, 73L, 74L, 77L, 78L, 79L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am interested in the frequency of how many countries (variable "location") have have 1, 2, 3 etc. agreements. `ftable(d$no.agreements)` produces the requested result: 23 countries have 1 agreement, 2 countries have 8 agreements...

```
  1  2  3  4  5 10

 23  8  7  1  1  1
```

I am now wondering whether there is a direct way to **add a further row (!) which includes the names of the countries contained each in each category**, e.g. the 1 country with 10 agreements is Chad, the 1 country with 5 agreements is Angola etc. The respective cell in the additional row would include the all the relavant country names (as string).

Of course I could identify the names of the countries by e.g. d[d$no.agreements==10,c("location")],and repeat this for all frequencies and create a table manually e.g in Excle. But I was wondering whether there isn't a more direct way which would insert the names of the locations as a list (?) into the cells of the additional row.

It would make things simply much more efficient. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `aggregate()` to summarise tables.

```
aggregate(location~no.agreements,data=d,FUN="unique")
```

Comment: many thanks. your suggested command gives me the names of the countries as a list. that's what I had been struggling with.  however, the count of the agreements got lost. Eventually, I came up with 

AgreementPerCountry <- aggregate(location~no.agreements,data=d,FUN="unique") #without count

AgreementPerCountry$no.countries <- sapply(AgreementPerCountry$location, length) #adds count

Answer (score 1):

Those aren't really rows but are rather a vector of column names and a single vector of counts. If you wanted a list of names for each named column you can use `tapply`:

```
> tapply(d$location, d$no.agreements, c)
$`1`
 [1] "Bangladesh"     "Cambodia"       "Colombia"      
 [4] "Comoros"        "Congo"          "Croatia"       
 [7] "El Salvador"    "Georgia"        "Guatemala"     
[10] "Guinea Bissau"  "Haiti"          "Macedonia"     
[13] "Mali"           "Mexico"         "Moldova"       
[16] "Mozambique"     "Nepal"          "Rwanda"        
[19] "Senegal"        "South Africa"   "Tajikistan"    
[22] "Uganda"         "United Kingdom"

$`2`
[1] "Bosnia-Herzegovina"                  
[2] "Democratic Republic of Congo (Zaire)"
[3] "Djibouti"                            
[4] "India"                               
[5] "Indonesia"                           
[6] "Niger"                               
[7] "Serbia (Yugoslavia)"                 
[8] "Somalia"                             

$`3`
[1] "Afghanistan"      "Burundi"          "Liberia"         
[4] "Papua-New Guinea" "Philippines"      "Sierra Leone"    
[7] "Sudan"           

$`4`
[1] "C\x99te d'Ivoire"

$`5`
[1] "Angola"

$`10`
[1] "Chad"
```

There a a couple of ways these could be delivered in a bundle:

```
 as.data.frame( tapply(d$location, d$no.agreements, function(x) list(x, length(x)))    )
                                                                                                                                                                          tapply(d$location, d$no.agreements, function(x) list(x, length(x)))
1  Bangladesh, Cambodia, Colombia, Comoros, Congo, Croatia, El Salvador, Georgia, Guatemala, Guinea Bissau, Haiti, Macedonia, Mali, Mexico, Moldova, Mozambique, Nepal, Rwanda, Senegal, South Africa, Tajikistan, Uganda, United Kingdom, 23
2                                                                                                                Bosnia-Herzegovina, Democratic Republic of Congo (Zaire), Djibouti, India, Indonesia, Niger, Serbia (Yugoslavia), Somalia, 8
3                                                                                                                                                        Afghanistan, Burundi, Liberia, Papua-New Guinea, Philippines, Sierra Leone, Sudan, 7
4                                                                                                                                                                                                                         C\x99te d'Ivoire, 1
5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   Angola, 1
10                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    Chad, 1
> do.call(rbind, tapply(d$location, d$no.agreements, function(x) list(x, length(x))))
   [,1]               [,2]
1  Character,23       23  
2  Character,8        8   
3  Character,7        7   
4  "C\x99te d'Ivoire" 1   
5  "Angola"           1   
10 "Chad"             1
```